# wrap a CloudStorageAccount creation in a try:catch block

Tags: c#, azure

I have the following C: Console program:

```
namespace AS2_Folder_Monitor
{
    class Program
    {
        private static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")); //points to the azure storage account
```

In case there is a problem with the connection string or Azure related issue I would like a try/block here.

Obviously you can't insert a try at the top of a class like this.
So, how can I handle errors?

I cannot seem to move the storageAccount down into Main either.
When I try that I get '} expected'

[image]

Comment: have you tried removing the `private static`? so it can me moved inside the main

Comment: Thank you pnadalini - I need to to be globally accessible however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing up because the term `private` or `static` can't be used inside a method.

So you can declare your `CloudStorageAccount` object inside the `try-catch` like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;
    }
}
```

Another approach can be declaring your object outside of the `Main` and then instantiating it in the `try`

```
private static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrapping the Parse method in a try-catch section to handle connection string issues, take a look at the CloudStorageAccount class static [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.tryparse?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_CloudStorageAccount_TryParse_System_String_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_CloudStorageAccount__) method. It will indicate whether a connection string can be parsed or not.

Implement it like this

```
If(CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"), out storageAccount))
{
     //use the storageAccount here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is a great suggestion for a improvement but I had already accepted another answer.